# Document resize event is not working in javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I want to look for a resize event and then set the graph's current `width` based upon widow width.

Below is the code that registers an event inside the `useEffect` -

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    let cb = function (e) {
      console.log('event happened');
      console.log('width: ', window.innerWidth);
      console.log('height', window.innerHeight);
    };
    // window.onresize = cb;
    document.addEventListener('resize', cb);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('resize', cb);
  }, []);
```

None of the above logs working. And if I use `onresize` to listen event it works. This is happening for Chrome as well for Mozilla.

What I am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `document` to `window` it works.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    let cb = function (e) {
      console.log('event happened');
      console.log('width: ', window.innerWidth);
      console.log('height', window.innerHeight);
    };
    // window.onresize = cb;
    window.addEventListener('resize', cb);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', cb);
  }, []);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mirzakhani-sd8hmz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: is it fired only for the window?? Why only for window?

Comment: Only on window and html elements: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

Comment: I have never used `window.addEventListener` before! Thanks mate!